# Trying to restrict link length in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm writing a code that models phage-bacteria interactions. Under certain conditions I want phages (I created a breed) to link with cells (another breed). I want them to only link if they're within the same patch.
This is the code:

```
to create-attach-link
 if random 100 < live-attach-prob
  [
   ask cells-here
   [
    create-link-with one-of phages-here
   ]
  set color red
  set attached? true
  ]
end
```

However, the cells still seem to be linking with phages on the other side of the grid. I feel like this should be a simple fix, and I'm overlooking a patch command that will fix this.

Comment: Are you sure they're not just linking and then moving slightly?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, I don't think it's in the code you've shown us — you're using `phages-here` correctly to strict linkages to the same patch.